# Calculate:$\int \frac{1}{(x+1)^\frac{3}{4}(x+2)^{\frac{5}{4}}}\ dx$

Tags: integration

Calculate following integration

$$\int \frac{1}{(x+1)^\frac{3}{4}(x+2)^{\frac{5}{4}}}\ dx$$

Comment: partial fractions?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: This is not an elementary integral.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal It actually is elementary, but the substitution I used is weird(I have seen this kind of integral before, which is the only reason I  got it). Any easier substitution, you can think of?

Comment: Sorry, I was evaluating the wrong integral.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\dfrac{1}{(x+1)^{\frac{3}{4}}(x+2)^{\frac{5}{4}}}=\dfrac{1}{(x+1)^{2}(\dfrac{x+2}{x+1})^{\frac{5}{4}}}=\dfrac{1}{(x+1)^{2}(1+\dfrac{1}{x+1})^{\frac{5}{4}}}$ So, make a $\dfrac{1}{x+1}$ substitution and we get the answer.

Comment: Or better yet, $1+\frac1{x+1}$.  Nice work!

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$I=\int \frac{1}{(x+1)^\frac{3}{4}(x+2)^{\frac{5}{4}}}\ dx=\int\frac{dx}{\left(\frac{x+1}{x+2}\right)^{3/4}(x+2)^2}$$ 
Now we pose $t=\frac{x+1}{x+2}$ then $x=\frac{1-2t}{t-1}$ and $dx=\frac{dt}{(t-1)^2}$, so
$$I=\int t^{-3/4}dt=4t^{1/4}+C,$$
hence
$$I=4\left(\frac{x+1}{x+2}\right)^{1/4}+C.$$